# 3 2560x1440 on Mac OS X without Mac Pro

Tags: windows-7, mac, remote, remote-control

I am trying my very best to do this but I am failing to succeed... :/

1) I have a 2011 Mac Mini (1 1280x1024 monitor) (Dual core i5, 8GB RAM)
2) I have a windows PC (3 2560x1440 Korean monitors) (i5 2500K, 16GB RAM)

[b]I need to use MAC OS X 10.8 on 3 2560x1440 (I CAN'T buy a MAC PRO)[/b]. I need it as fast as possible (real time speed if possible).

In my understanding i can do this using:

A) VMWare (slow on single 1080 monitor, must be terrible slow on 2560x1440). Last option.

B) Hackintosh (my PC supports it but will i experience crashes etc?)

C) Remote control the mac (dual Gbit Ethernet on both PC and Mac. Communication speed is 250MB/s) (Team View, RealVNC and lots of other do not support virtual monitors at this resolution...)

A, B or C will work better? If C please help me, what software i need?

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer, but (B) Hackintosh will definitely be the fastest option - if you can get it to work.

There is a pay-for version of RealVNC [as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602985/vnc-viewer-with-multiple-monitors) which has multi-monitor support, so option (C) is possible.

Lastly, if you can get the hardware acceleration of VMWare (or VirtualBox) to work, it should also be possible to get it working at decent speed.